# trying to show HTML, CSS, Javascript and Jquery offline

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to send stuff for people to look at that includes HTML, CSS, Javascript, and Jquery, but I don't know how to send it to people so they can check it out without creating a website and buying a domain and having them see it there.  Is there a way to send it so people can actually look at it (not just the code) or is there a different work around?

Comment: Just zip them all and open the HTML file.....

Comment: Make sure all files are local and included in the .zip-file or however you send it (including js-files such as the jQuery library or similiar if you use that).

Comment: As long as there are no server-side scripts then you can just package everything in a zip file and the recipient should be able to open the files locally on their machine.

Comment: For web-based solutions, I use [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) or [Codepen](http://codepen.io/pen/).

Comment: ...you're asking for a workaround, but did you even try to see if it works first?

Comment: everything works on my comp, I'm just concerned because i'm using images and links to my js and css files.  I don't know what you mean when you say make sure all files are local.  Are you saying to save all of that stuff in a file and include it in the zipped file that I send and make sure the links reference correctly?

Answer (score 0):

You could open a site with 000webhost for free and upload them there. I daresay that's not actually off line but it might be handy anyway.

Comment: that's a great option if it's online, is it 000webhost.com?  Is there any danger doing something like that there?  I don't want to try to impress someone with my awesome progress by shutting down their company with a virus ;)

Comment: As far as I know 000webhost are not prone to malware although you can never be certain. They are a little unreliable in that the site may go down, crash or similar. I've found them fine for simple demo pages but would not want to host a serious business there. You get what you pay for to some extent.

Answer (score 0):

Put it all in a folder, zip it, email it to them, tell them to decompress it and click on the HTML file. It will open in their default browser. Alternatively, if you need to get something from the web, you can put it in a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)